# Partial derivatives are zero in some point, when the limit in boundary points are zero.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity, partial-derivative

Let $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ an open set and $f:U\to \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function such as his first order partial derivatives there exist in $U$. Let suppose that $$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=0$$ for all $a\in \partial U$. Show that there is $c\in U$ such as, $$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(c)=0$$ for all $i\in \{1,\dots,n\}$.

Comment: Is $U$ bounded?

Comment: What have you tried? We are not here to do homework, we are here to help you in what you did not understand. Can you please show your efforts and fails? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to include the condition that $U$ is bounded as well. Otherwise we can construct counterexamples like $U=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2|x>0,y>0\}$, and $f(x,y)=xy$.

Hint: We can extend $f$ to a continuous function $\bar f:\overline U\to\mathbb R$, such that $\bar f(x)=0$ for any $x\in\partial U$. Since $\overline U$ is closed and bounded, it is compact. So we can apply extreme value theorem, there exists $c_1,c_2
\in \overline U$ such that $\bar f(c_1)\geq \bar f(x)$ and $\bar f(c_2)\leq \bar f(x)$ for any $x\in \overline U$.